# Find $A$ given $A^2$ and $B$ and $(A^2)^{-1} = A^{-1}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

This excersice took place in class I had today. The exercise was the following:

> Let the regular matrix $A$,$B$:
>
> $$A^2 = \left[ \begin{matrix} 2 &-2 & 2\\ -2 & 2 & 2 \\ 4&4&-4 \end{matrix} \right]  \hspace{2cm}  B = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 &-1 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1&3&-1 \end{matrix} \right]$$
>
> Knowing that $(A^2)^{-1} = A^{-1}B$, find A.

**My Attempt**

During the exam I tried the following:

$(A^2)^{-1} = A^{-1}B \Leftrightarrow A^2(A^2)^{-1} = A^2A^{-1}B \Leftrightarrow I_n = AB \Leftrightarrow A = B^{-1}$

And procedeed to find the inverse of B, which is:

$A = B^{-1} = \left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{2} &\frac{-5}{4} &  1\\ 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{4}&0 \end{matrix} \right]$

But, as I tend to make silly mistakes, I figured out that it would be a better way to do find $A$ just by using matrix products. We had $I_n = AB \Leftrightarrow A = A^2B$. Using this method I got that

$A = A^2B = \left[ \begin{matrix} 2 & 0 &  2\\ 2 & 12 & -6 \\ -4& -8&12 \end{matrix} \right]$

But as you can see the $2$ matrix are different. **Where is the mistake in my logic?**

Another thing I noticed is that $I_n = AB \Leftrightarrow A*I_n*B = A*(AB)*B \Leftrightarrow I_n = AB = A^2B^2$, but $A^2B^2$ isn't the identity matrix, so maybe the exercise is wrong, but I rather not rush into that thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the properties of determinant to show that the given relationship does not hold.
$$\det ((A^2)^{-1})=-\frac1{64}=\det (A^{-1})\cdot(-4)$$
from the given relationship and properties of determinant. So $\det (A)=64\cdot 4$ and this cannot be true.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is broken, here is a precise statement showing how it is broken.

Let $B=\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 &-1 & 2\\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1&3&-1 \end{matrix} \right].$

For every invertible matrix $A$, at least one of the following are false:

1. $A^2 = \left[ \begin{matrix} 2 &-2 & 2\\ -2 & 2 & 2 \\ 4&4&-4 \end{matrix} \right]$
2. $(A^2)^{-1}=A^{-1}B$

**Proof.** 
If 2. holds, then
$$
\det \bigl((A^2)^{-1}\bigl)=\det (A^{-1}B).
$$

By direct computation, $\det B=-4$. On the other hand,
$$
\det\ \left[ \begin{matrix} 2 &-2 & 2\\ -2 & 2 & 2 \\ 4&4&-4 \end{matrix} \right]=-64.
$$
Consequently if 1. and 2. both hold, then $(-64)^{-1}=(\det A)^{-1}\cdot (-4),\text{ or equivalently, } \det A=256.$ But this contradicts 1. Thus, it there does not exist any invertible matrix satisfying both 1. and 2. simultaneously.

Answer (score -2):

Long story short, matrix multiplication is not commutative.

---

Te equation $A=A^2B$ is not correct. From the equation $$(A^2)^{-1} = A^{-1}B$$

you have to multiply it by $A$ from the left to get
$$A(A^2)^{-1} = B$$

and the multiply it by $A^2$ **from the right** and you get

$$A=B\cdot A^2$$

which is not the same as $A=A^2B$.

---

However, even using $A=BA^2$ results in two different calculations of what $A$ is, and this seems to me like a mistake in the exercise. Indeed, from $(A^2)^{-1} = A^{-1}B$, it should follow that $I=A^2A^{-1}B=AB$, and from that, it should follow that $A=B^{-1}$. However, it is not true that $(B^{-1})^2=A^2$ which means that $A=B^{-1}$ cannot hold, which is a contradiction.

Comment: It is correct, though, because multiplying on the left by $A^2$ yields $I=AB$, and then multiplying by $A$ on the left again yields $A=A^2 B$.  Once you have that $B$ is the inverse of $A$, you also know that it commutes with $A$, and so all commutativity issues disappear.  The issue is that the stated equality just doesn't hold.

Comment: @Aaron OK, sure, if OP used the fact that $B$ and $A$ commute, I wouldn't say they did anything wrong.

Comment: I am not sure OP did anything wrong (they used $(A^2)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^2$).